# How to share an existing dynamic array within Linux POSIX model in c language?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, posix, shared-memory

I have very big quickly growing (realloc, tcmalloc) dynamic array (about 2-4 billion double). After the growth ends I would like to share this array between two different applications. I know how to prepare shared memory region and copy my full-grown array into it, but this is too prodigally for memory, because I must to keep source and shared destination array at the same moment. Is it possible to share already existing dynamic array within POSIX model without copying?

**EDITED:**

Little bit explanation.

I am able to use memory allocation within POSIX model (shm_open() and others) but if I do it, I have to reallocate already shared memory segment many times (reading digits row by row from database to memory). It is much more overhead in comparison with simple realloc().

I have one producer, who reads from database and writes into shared memory.

I can't know beforehand how many records are present in the database and therefore I can't know the size of the shared array before the allocation. For this reason I have to reallocate big array while producer is reading row by row from database. After the memory is shared and filled, another applications  reads data from shared array. Sometimes size of this big shared array could be changed and be replenished with new data.

Comment: What is all that memory on your machine *for*?

Comment: Just one array about 2 billion (double) numbers for mathematical calculations received from DB.

Comment: How much does 16GB or even 32 GB of RAM cost?  How much does it cost to have you write code to use less RAM?

Comment: The more memory I have, the greater the number of such arrays I be able to load. My goal - to use memory more efficiently by eliminating excessive duplication.

Comment: In my understanding: 3 apps, one creates the dynamic array. Other two have to read it (soft) real-time. You know how to prepare shared memory. Why don't you alloc 2 contiguous mem, and share it in ping-pong: one producer, two consumers?

Comment: Question is not clear. Why can't you use shm as the allocator? Also why does the array has to be dynamically re-sizable? Why not a multi-threaded design?

Comment: Please **edit your question**, don't put additional information only in comments. And *show some source code*

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've added some explanations to my general question. I'm still preparing some source code at my question.

Comment: The edit does not motivate your question. You need to explain what kind of application do you exactly have in mind, and why have you chosen (probably wrongly) to use shared memory. So explain *what you want to achieve* (is it a computer vision project, a compiler project, a machine learning project....). You are only (too imprecisely) explaining *how you are coding* and that is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to share already existing dynamic array within POSIX model without copying?

No, that is not how shared memory works. Read [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

Copying two billion doubles might take a few seconds.

Perhaps you could use [mremap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html).

BTW, for POSIX shared memory, most computers limit the size of the of the segment shared with [shm_open(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) to a few megabytes (not gigabytes). Heuristically the maximal shared size (on the whole computer) should be much less than half of the RAM available.

My feeling is that your design is inadequate and you should not use shared memory in your case. You did not explain what problem you are trying to solve and how is the data *modified* 
(Did you consider using some [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS)?). What are the [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) issues?

Your question smells a lot like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so you really should explain more, motivate it much more, and *also* give a broader, higher-level picture.

Comment: Thank you for expanded answer to my general question. I have to take some time to prepare answers to yours.

Comment: Please take time to improve your question and give the overall motivation (including explaining in more details what kind of application you have in mind)